# Finding if the infinite series diverges or converges

Tags: limits, inequality, summation, divergent-series

I am attempting to solve a problem which requires finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \lceil e^ek+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil - \lceil e^ek-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil$.

My attempt at solving this problem went as follows:

Given that we know $n \leq \lceil n \rceil <n+1 $ and $m \leq \lceil m \rceil <m+1 $ where n and m are real numbers, $\lceil n \rceil - \lceil m \rceil$ can be described as $n-m -1 \leq \lceil n \rceil - \lceil m \rceil < n-m +1 $. Applying this to the original equation and symplifying a bit, we know:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} k} -1 \leq \lceil e^ek+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil - \lceil e^ek-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil < \frac{2}{\sqrt{5} k}+1 $

Next I took the infinite sum of the inequality:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} k}) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty ( \lceil e^ek+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil - \lceil e^ek-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} k} \rceil) < \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} k}) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1) $

The right side of the inequality clearly diverges to $\infty$ because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{\sqrt{5} k}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \times$ (the harmonic series), and that added to another divergent series must diverge.

As for the left side of the inequality, I am unsure how to mathematically show that the sequence diverges to $-\infty$, although I was able to confirm its divergence using Wolfram Alfa.

I am fairly sure the orgininal problem diverges to $\infty$ but using my method I was only able to confirm that the solution is between $-\infty$ and $\infty$. I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate the left side of the inequality to show it diverges or if there is any other convergence test or methods to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the problem revolves around finding the number of times $e^ek$ is within $\frac 1{\sqrt 5k}$ of an integer, and the difference between the two ceiling functions will always be $\in\{0,1\}$. Is there anything you know about rationalizing the decimal expansion of $e^e$ and how close a given $k$ could bring it to an integer?

Comment: @abiessu Thank you for the new perspective, I had not looked at the problem that way. As for rationalizing e^e, it is unknown if e^e is rational or irrational so  rationalizing the decimal expansion is, as of now, impossible.  I am unclear as to what you mean by "how close a given k could bring it to an integer".

Comment: By "rationalizing $e^e$" what I meant was, pick an integer $k$ that makes the value $e^e$ as close to rational as possible, then multiples of that $k$ can be used to make $e^e$ as close to an integer as possible.  If there is a finite count of such $k$ that "as close as possible" is within the $\frac 1{\sqrt 5k}$ "error margin" then the sum is finite, otherwise it is infinite.